# GPG how to write enc output to stdout

Tags: gnupg

On Linux, I can generate an enc message using,

```
gpg --recipient Alice --encrypt source.txt
```

How can I force it to print to stdout, instead of writing to source.txt.asc?

**SOLUTION:**

```
gpg --recipient Alice --encrypt --armor --output - source.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

Using the `--output` option.

```
gpg --recipient Alice --output - --encrypt source.txt
```

should sent the encrypted message to stdout.

Comment: You will want to use --armor so its is readable ASCII not binary